# How to change the measurement unit of X axis on Longitudinal Profile using Profile Tools Plugin QGIS

Tags: qgis-plugins, elevation-profile

I have an issue with measurement unit of X axis when I plot longitudinal profile using Profile Tools Plugin QGIS like the screenshot attached below.
[image]
QGIS version : 3.28.9 Firenze

**What I have done are:**

1. Reproject the vector layer (river polyline) to EPSG 32749 WGS 84: UTM 49S
2. Warp (Reproject) raster layer of DEM to to EPSG 32749 WGS 84: UTM 49S as well.

I also have red some topics related to my question, but I cannot find the solution.

What should I do to fix this issue?